# Path environment variable in console of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: path, terminal, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

This is what is appearing as soon as I open my terminal

> bash: export:
>   `.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/play:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/elasticsearch/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
>
> export PATH=/home/rocio/
>   .rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/usr/local/play:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/elasticsearch/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games':
>   not a valid identifier
>
> bash: /usr/local/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /home/rocio/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory
>
> bash: /home/rocio/usr/bin: No such file or directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin/: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
>
> bash: /bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory
>
> bash: /bin: Is a directory

I'm not able to use `clear` or `ls` or `sudo commands`
It says, they are in `/usr/bin or /bin`. These are not in your path. So cannot run those commands.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you edited your shell initialization files, and introduced a syntax error in the assignments for setting `PATH`.  If that is only the files in your home directory (versus editing `/etc/profile`, etc), you can recover by renaming your files, closing the shell (with <kbd>control/D</kbd>) and then starting the terminal again.

Most Ubuntu users are using `bash`, whose name-completion probably still works with this problem.

To rename, use the full path of `mv`, e.g.,

```
for n in .inputrc .bashrc .bash_profile .profile; do /bin/mv $n $n.orig;done
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem. I added some of those commands unknowingly into bashrc file in the home directory. I just had to delete those extra commands in the file. Everything was running fine again.

So, in order to resolve any such issues. Check your bashrc file. As your console first runs that file before starting.

Thank you.